# Laravel 5.2 - file not found (while it's there);

Tags: file, laravel, storage

When I want to move a file laravel gives me an error, and I don't really understand why.

This is the error I receive

> local.ERROR: exception 'League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException' with
>   message 'File not found at path:
>   **Ad_Pictures/waitinglist/6f6232707e65c7803f7af248a07cb8cesony-z5-familytn videos ad.jpg'**

However, when I look on the server it days the file is there (*it's the 4th one*)

[image: #4]

Here's my code I use to move the file

```
        $newAd = DB::table('ads')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
        $Ad = Ad::find($newAd->id);

        $oldDestination_path = "Ad_Pictures/waitinglist/";
        $newDestination_path = "Ad_Pictures/".$newAd->id."/";

        if(!is_dir($newDestination_path))
        {
            mkdir($newDestination_path);
        }
        Storage::move($oldDestination_path.'/'.$file, $newDestination_path.'/'.$file);
```

He makes the new directory without a problem, he just doesn't move the file in it.

Comment: the screenshot is cropped - which directory is shown exactly - is ith Ad_Pictures/waitinglist or /Ad_Pictures/?

Comment: And: did you try the same code with an file having no spaces in the filename? You never know... ;-)

Comment: try do dump the dedtination and name variables, i thing laravel is lookibg in the storage folder while you have the file in public foldef

Comment: @herrjeh42 its's /waitinglist

Answer (score 0):

Full code is not shown but I'll let you know that by default the folder is storage/app you need to get file from there
if your file is located somewhere else you can make your own disk in config/filesystems e.g. `'myDisk' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' =>base_path('xyzFolder'),
        ],`

and you can call it like

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$data = Storage::disk('myDisk')->get('myFile.txt');
```

this is obviously to get file and you can perform any other function by following laravel docs.